# Oracle Trigger with condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have this trigger which getting near to what I want to accomplished but after trying I still cannot make it done.

### What I've done

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TR_UPD_TEST_TABLE_B
  AFTER INSERT ON TEST_TABLE_A
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN

  FOR VAL IN (SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE_B A WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID) LOOP
    IF :NEW.QTY_RECEIVED > VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED THEN
      UPDATE TEST_TABLE_B A SET A.QTY_RECEIVED = 888 WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID;
    ELSE
      UPDATE TEST_TABLE_B A SET A.QTY_RECEIVED = 111 WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

### The Problem

By using `IF :NEW.QTY_RECEIVED > VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED`, I want to compare the :NEW.QTY_RECEIVED with each record but it seems that it total up all the records' quantity. Therefore the statement always jump to the `ELSE` because the total quantity is bigger than the `:NEW.QTY_RECEIVED`.

Comment: The for loop is required? try without the for loop.

Comment: The problem is that each update will update all rows from `TABLE_B` (with `table_a`'s id). You need to specify the primary key of `TABLE_B` in the update (or use rowids)

Comment: I tried using rownum but to no success. @Polppan Yes The for loop is required because I will have a total quantity e.g 5000 and it needs to loop through set of records and deduct the quantity until it become 0.

Comment: @TanSiongZhe. Dont use rownum. Try using rowid, use A.ID = :NEW.ID and Val.rowid. get rowid in the cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a loop. simply do it with a single update and case.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TR_UPD_TEST_TABLE_B
  AFTER INSERT ON TEST_TABLE_A
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN
      UPDATE TEST_TABLE_B A SET A.QTY_RECEIVED = 
      case when :NEW.QTY_RECEIVED > QTY_PRE_RECEIVED then 888 else 111 end
      WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID ;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I finally came out.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER TR_UPD_TEST_TABLE_B
  AFTER INSERT ON TEST_TABLE_A
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  BALQTY NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BALQTY := :NEW.QTY_RECEIVED;
  FOR VAL IN (SELECT A.*
                FROM TEST_TABLE_B A
               WHERE A.ID = :NEW.ID
               ORDER BY A.ID1) LOOP

    IF BALQTY >= VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED THEN
      UPDATE TEST_TABLE_B A
         SET A.QTY_RECEIVED     = A.QTY_RECEIVED + VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED,
             A.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED = 0
       WHERE A.ID1 = VAL.ID1
         AND VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED <> 0;
      BALQTY := BALQTY - VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED;
    ELSIF BALQTY < VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED AND BALQTY <> 0 AND BALQTY > 0 THEN
      UPDATE TEST_TABLE_B A
         SET A.QTY_RECEIVED     = A.QTY_RECEIVED + BALQTY,
             A.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED = VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED - BALQTY
       WHERE A.ID1 = VAL.ID1
         AND VAL.QTY_PRE_RECEIVED <> 0;
      BALQTY := 0;
    ELSIF BALQTY = 0 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

END;
```